# GoBackToRootAsync with modal navigation in Prism

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, prism

So the application is using modal stack instead of navigation stack, here's a sample of the App class:

```
protected override async void OnInitialized()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MainPage");
}

protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage, MainPageViewModel>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Page1>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Page2>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Page3>();
}
```

I navigate from `MainPage` to `Page1` to `Page2` to `Page3`, for example, in `Page2ViewModel`:

```
public DelegateCommand ToPage3Command => new DelegateCommand(() => 
NavigationService.NavigateAsync("Page3", useModalNavigation: true));
```

in `Page3` I want to go back to the root (`MainPage`), so I do this:

```
 public DelegateCommand ToMainPageCommand => new DelegateCommand(async () =>
 {
     var navResult = await NavigationService.GoBackToRootAsync(new NavigationParameters
     { { KnownNavigationParameters.UseModalNavigation, true } });
 });
```

but `navResult.Exception` gets a `System.InvalidOperationException` exception:

> Sequence contains no elements

I'm trying this based on the comment by Brian [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1621#issuecomment-438477279).
but the exception thrown indicates that `GoBackToRootAsync` only possible with navigation stack:
https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/a4c131ab271fcab26c3ed9c5e3eb3316ec02a4ce/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Forms/Navigation/PageNavigationService.cs#L198

If it's not possible with modal stack, is there any workaround without switching to use navigation stack?

The main reason I want to do this is that I want to navigate to the `MainPage` without re-initializing it and clear the modal stack, so any solution that achieves this is welcome.

Comment: I had this issue, but I'm not using modal nav, so I'm not 100% certain if we having the same issue.

I needed to specify the root page in my navigation stack:
 `await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/NavigationPage/MainPage", navParams);`

After that you can navigate normally and then use GoBackToRootAsync